# kubernetes dashboard not starting : giving error

Tags: kubernetes

I have created 3 Virtualbox VMs -> installed CentOS7 -> installed kubernetes via kubespray.

Dashboard container refuses to run after VM restart. Gives the following error:

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).initInsecureClient(0xc4201bf320)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:335 +0x9a
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.(*clientManager).init(0xc4201bf320)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:297 +0x47
github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client.NewClientManager(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/client/manager.go:365 +0x84
main.main()
        /home/travis/build/kubernetes/dashboard/.tmp/backend/src/github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/src/app/backend/dashboard.go:92 +0x13b
2018/03/28 11:11:49 Could not init in cluster config: open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory
```

Please help. I am a newbie in kubernetes and unable to find any clue on resolving it.

Comment: I have started ``` kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*' ``` to start dashboard. however, I dont know which token to give to dashboard so that I can login into it.

Comment: `open /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token: no such file or directory` is caused by the Pod not having a `serviceAccountName`, or the one it does have is bogus

Comment: _I dont know which token to give to dashboard so that I can login into it_ the short version is that ideally you would create a `ClusterRoleBinding` for yourself, then create a `serviceAccont` that represents you, which will materialize a `Secret` containing the JWT that allows you to auth. Whew, RBAC. I have actually never gotten the kubconfig-based login form to work, as it always produces an HTTP error on `POST`

Comment: Thanks Daniel. There doesnt seem to be a newbie friendly tutorial to start with. is there a recommendation on the steps to follow, to learn kubernetes easily ?

Answer (score 0):

I updated the kubespray playbooks (synced with github). I guess few issues were resolved due to that.
The steps to connect/configure to dashboard are as follows

```

```
# create admin user, as follows:
kubectl create  -f admin.user
kubectl create  -f clusterrolebinding.yaml
# get admin secret token
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
# get port on which dashboard is running
kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard
# open the url, add the token found above to it. BINGO ! dashboard should open :)
```

```